# how to generate a vector which satisfy some conditions?

Tags: r, vector, sample

everyone!
**how to generate a vector which satisfy some conditions?**
Problem: generate a vector `a` such that `length(a)=400000` which is made up of 8 elements:`0, 5, 10, 50, 500, 5000, 50000, 300000`. Each element appears a set number of times, namely `290205, 100000, 8000, 1600, 160, 32, 2, 1`, respectively. Further, `a` is blocked into 4,000 "groups" of 100 consecutive elements; call them `a_k, k=1,...,4000`. These groups must satisfy the following:

1. The sum of every group exceeds 150, i.e. `sum_i a_k_i>150` for all `k`.
2. The elements `5`, `10` and `50` appear between 25 and 29 times in each group, i.e. for all `k`, the set `{i|a_i_k in (5,10,50)}` has magnitude between 25 and 29.
3. `0` never appears more than 8 times in a row in any group.

I have tried this many times, but it does not seem to work:
My current code is as follows:

```
     T <- 4*10^(5)   # data size  
            x <- c(0, 5, 10, 50, 500, 5000, 50000, 300000)      #seed vector  
            t <- c(290205, 100000, 8000, 1600, 160, 32, 2, 1)   #frequency  
            A <- matrix(0, 4000, 100)    #4000 groups  
            k <- rep(0, times = 8)        #record the number of seeds   
            for(m in 1:4000) {        
            p <- (t - k)/(T - 100*(m - 1))      #seed probability  
            A[, m] <- sample(x, 100, replace = TRUE, prob = p)  #group m   
            sm <- 0         
            i <- 0    
              for(j in 1:92) {  
                  if(sum(A[m,j:j + 8])==0){  
                     if(A[m,j] > 0 & A[m,j] < 500) {i <- i+1}  
                        sm <- sm+A[100*m+j]       
                    }  
                   else j <- 0   
                }                
                       if (sm >= 150 & i > 24 & i < 30 & j != 0) {    
                           m <- m + 1  
                           for (n in seq_len(x)) {  
                               k[n] <- sum(A[, m+1] == x[n]) + k[n]  
                            }  
                        }  
            }
```

Comment: Can you detail it ?Thanks for your comments

Comment: Nevermind about the previous comment.  I didn't look at your code earlier.

Comment: This is a big task. I would create small examples like sample 4 values that sum to 50 and must repeat twice or other conditions. Then build techniques from there.

Comment: One ambiguity about the third condition: `0` can _never_ appear more than 8 times in a row, or this condition only binds within groups? e.g., is it OK if `a[95:105]==0`?

Comment: another question: are you trying to come up with _just one_ such vector, or are you trying to write a function that can generate _many_ such vectors? If you want a function, should the function be able (in theory) to produce _all_ such vectors?

Comment: @MichaelChirico,Thanks for your interesting comments. I come late.First, all conditions are considered in groups, so a[95:105] is ok. Second, finding a satisfied vector a is primary goal, all possible vectors is secondary. If we can make it ,it cannot better.

Answer (score 2):

I can start it off and maybe someone can help get to the next step. My approach is to start with the constraints and let `sample` work out the numbers.

```
set.seed(77)
choose <- c(0,5,10,50,500,5000,50000,300000)
freqs <- c(290205,100000,8000,1600,160,32,2,1)
probs <- freqs/sum(freqs)
check.sum <- function(vec) sum(vec) >= 150
check.interval <- function(vec) abs(sum(vec %in% c(5,10,50))-27)<=2
check.runs <- function(vec, runmax=8) max(rle(vec)$lengths[rle(vec)$values==0]) <= runmax

check.all <- function(vector) {
  logicals <- c(check.sum(vector), 
                check.runs(vector),
                check.runs(vector)
                )
  return(all(logicals))

}

nums <- NULL
res <- list()
for(i in 1:4000) {
  nums <- numeric(100)
  while(!check.all(nums)) {nums <- sample(choose, 100, replace=T,prob=probs)}

  res[i] <- list(nums)
}

str(res)
List of 4000
 $ : num [1:100] 1e+01
```

So this gets you a list of 4,000 groups of 100 numbers that fit the constraints. It only took about two seconds of system time.

Next step is for someone to get a way to build something similar except eliminate 300000 once it is used, and 50000 once it is used twice and so on.

Comment: this has the advantage that this approach can generate _all_ valid `a` once we build in the total counts condition. but I am not sure how to generalize--proceeding sequentially (repopulating counts after each group) is sure to fail.

Comment: if OP only needs one such vector my approach is better; if he only needs _many_ such vectors, we can just permute columns of my matrix before vectorizing. But my approach will also be hard to generalize to _all_ such vectors...

Comment: I agree, +1 on your solution. If there was a way to combine the two, the resulting solution would be powerful enough to automatically produce rule-based strings in a generalized context. @MichaelChirico

Comment: with the weighted sampling, it's doing a respectable job. pushing it to exact frequency matching may be a significant leap from here... the posterior frequencies are biased--I think the conditions favor draws with few `0`s and many large values.

Answer (score 2):

How about just doing it by construction? For example:

```
amat<-matrix(rep(c(rep(rep(c(0,5),c(8,3)),8),
               rep(c(0,NA),c(8,4))),4000),nrow=100)
amat[97:100,1:2205]<-c(rep(10,3),0)
amat[97:98,2206:4000]<-c(5,5)
amat[99:100,2206:2897]<-c(10,10)
amat[99:100,2898]<-c(5,50)
amat[99:100,2899:3307]<-c(5,50)
amat[99:100,3308:3902]<-c(50,50)
amat[which(is.na(amat))]<-rep(c(10,500,5000,5e4,3e5),c(1,160,32,2,1))

a<-c(amat)
```

This satisfies all your conditions:

Element counts:

```
>sapply(c(0,5,10,50,500,5000,50000,300000),function(x)length(which(a==x)))
[1] 290205 100000   8000   1600    160     32      2      1
```

Group sums:

```
> table(colSums(amat)>=150)

TRUE 
4000
```

`5,10,50` frequency:

```
> table(sapply(1:4000,function(x)abs(sum(amat[,x] %in% c(5,10,50))-27)<=2))

TRUE 
4000
```

Runs of `0`:

```
> table(sapply(1:4000,function(x)max(rle(amat[,x])$lengths[rle(amat[,x])$values==0])<=8))
#If this is slow, we can just use max(rle(amax[,x]))<=8
#  because there aren't many valid groups with strings of 9+
#  non-0 elements

TRUE 
4000
```

if in fact we're never allowed to have strings of 9 `0`s, we'll need to make a slight adjustment to groups 2:2206, because, e.g. `a[100:108]==0`

Comment: Construction is a good method ,but it not what I want . And if a fourth condition is added ,what if we do? in fact ,this question is simplified by my original question. Size bigger(to 10^8). The core question I think is that by what means  we  can fast search the sastified vector. Bigger size more probability(exponential growth)

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by @plafort's approach, I've come up with the following that seems to work very quickly and should be capable of generating *all* vectors satisfying your conditions:

```
elts<-c(0,5,10,50,500,5000,50000,300000)
freq<-c(290205,100000,8000,1600,160,32,2,1)
ngrp<-4000L

grp.cond1<-function(x)sum(x)>=150
grp.cond2<-function(x)abs(sum(x %in% c(5,10,50))-27)<=2
grp.cond3<-function(x)max(rle(x)$lengths[rle(x)$values==0])<=8

check.all<-function(mat){
  all(sapply(1:ncol(mat),function(y)grp.cond1(mat[,y])),
      sapply(1:ncol(mat),function(y)grp.cond2(mat[,y])),
      sapply(1:ncol(mat),function(y)grp.cond3(mat[,y])))}

while(!check.all(amat)){amat<-matrix(sample(rep(elts,freq)),ncol=ngrp)}
a<-c(amat)
```

I've also written the code in a way that should be easy to generalize to other element sets/counts, group numbers, and group-wise conditions.

Unfortunately it seems these conditions are pretty stringent, and it may take a long time to generate an acceptable `a`. I let the `while` loop run ~1300 times with no success...

Comment: That the probability of success appears to be less than 1 in 1300 suggests a constructive approach to this problem may be your best bet. Note that my other approach seems to be capable of generating about 10^2577 unique rearrangements of the groups; on the other hand, randomly happening upon one of these given this approach has probability roughly 10^(-116180).

Comment: Thanks again. I came into the same question. I think speeding up the search and figuring out a new search method is  effective and feasible.

Comment: Time to parallelize, I guess!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone! I have figured out my problem.

```
rm(list = ls())  
media <- matrix(rep(rep(c(0,5,NA),c(72,25,3)),4000),nrow=100)  
media[98:100,1:2400] <-c(10,10,10)  
media[98:99,2401:3200] <-c(50,10)  
media[98:99,3201:4000] <-c(50,0)  
media[100,2401:4000] <-rep(c(0,500,5000,50000,300000),c(1405,160,32,2,1))  
obj1 <- matrix(0,100L,4000)  
obj2 <-obj1  
grp.cond<-function(x) max(rle(x)$lengths[rle(x)$values==0])<=8  
elts<-c(0,5,10,50,500,5000,50000,300000)  
for(i in 1:4000){  
freq<-c(sapply(elts, function(x) length(which(media[,i]==x))))  
while(!grp.cond(obj1[,i])){obj1[,i]<-c(sample(rep(elts,freq)))}  
i<-i+1  
}  
elts1<-c(1:4000)  
freq1<-rep(1,times=4000)  
a1<-sample(rep(elts1,freq1))  
for(i in 1:4000){obj2[,i]<-obj1[,a1[i]]} 
a <- c(obj2)
```